# Incrementing regularly vs updating when value is needed

Tags: node.js

I am going to be creating some kind of chatbot game where you can use money to buy factories that generate you more money over time. What I'm wondering is whether I should add the generated money to their balance regularly (for example, every 1 minute) or if I should use dates to calculate how much money their factories have earned and update their balance ONLY when the data is needed, such as when they check their balance or when they attempt to purchase something.

Comment: I would think the latter is less computationally costly. It only performs an operation at the end whereas the other one does every one minute. So performance wise the second option should be better. However, I'm not sure what you're criteria is.

Comment: @AlirezaAzimi I suppose I don't have any criteria in mind, I just wonder what the downfalls would be of both options. I also wonder if the first option is really as inefficient as it sounds.